# Why does "if keyboard.is_pressed('q'): " not execute in my code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, keyboard-events

In my code, in the f(), "kbd.is_pressed('q'):" doesn't work. It doesn't print the message and the loop doesn't end when 'q' is pressed.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import multiprocessing as mp
import keyboard as kbd

x = 0
frames = []

def f(conn):
    global x
    while x == 0:
        frames.append(1)
        conn.send([42, None, 'hello', frames])
        if kbd.is_pressed('q'):
            print("Q was pressed.")
            break
    conn.close()
    print("Pipe is closed!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    print(mp.current_process)
    print(parent_conn.recv())   # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    f(child_conn)
    print(str(frames))
    p.join()
    print("CPU's = " + str(mp.cpu_count()))
    p.terminate()
    print(mp.parent_process)
```

Comment: Where does this `keyboard` library come from? (It's certainly not part of the standard library). How is it implemented? Is it trying to interact with a GUI framework? Is it just doing a TTY read? Etc. And can you reproduce the problem _without_ `multiprocessing`, or is it strictly something that happens when both `keyboard` and `multiprocessing` are used together?

Comment: Looks to me like it's https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard, which means it's using `/dev/uinput`. That's... a very low-level interface (which is why it needs `sudo` to grant root permissions, which most GUI applications don't have or need). Unless you're doing something like QA automation, I'd probably choose a different tool.

Comment: (Also, is there a reason you're using multiprocessing here? Seems much more like a job for threading -- there's no reason to try to bypass the GIL).

Comment: How does a global variable interact within multiprocessing?

Comment: First, X was there before I made some changes. Now, I have while True instead of while x==0. Second, I need to bypass the GIL and use multiprocessing.

Comment: What tool should I use instead of the keyboard module?